# Нахождения углов Эйлера из вектора направления

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, линейная-алгебра

Моя программа из углов Эейлера, которые хранятся в виде трехкомпонентного вектора `A(Ax, Ay, Az)`, получает матрицу поворота порядка `ZXY` (умножение матриц идет с конца). Далее умножает эту матрицу на единичный вектор `O(1, 0, 0)`, получая при этом вектор направления `D`. Формулой это можно записать так:
`D = (Z(Az) * (X(Ax) * Y(Ay))) * O`

У меня реализована данная функция, которая получает единичный вектор направления из углов Эйлера, но мне нужна еще и функция, которая может получить, наоборот, углы из вектора направления. В векторной алгебре я не силен, поэтому ума не приложу как преобразовать вышенаписанное уравнение, чтобы выразить от туда вектор `A`. Как это сделать? Если что, система координат у меня правая, так как работаю с opengl

Answer (score 0):

Из вектора направления D нельзя однозначно получить углы Эйлера. Можно получить heading/yaw- проекцию на OXY, pitch - угол между heading и D, но roll - увы.

(как наклонены крылья самолёта - из направления фюзеляжа не понять, нужен ещё опорный вектор - например, up - вектор направления крыши/киля)

Comment: Допустим мне roll не нужен, и он всегда будет равен 0. Как мне тогда найденный yaw и pitch перевести в углы Эйлера ZXY порядка?